# Configuration of modwsgi with wamp server

Tags: django, wamp, mod-wsgi, wampserver

I would like to deploy a Django application in a production environment (Windows Server 2012 R2).
I am unable to configure modwsgi for a WAMP server.

There are a few posts for this topic, however it seems that all are old and not applicable now. All the posts say that I should have the `.so` file of modwsgi, but I am unable to find this file.

I have downloaded the source code for modwsgi and also `.whl` file, but don't know how to configure.

System configuration is as follows:

- Operating System: Windows Server 2012 R2 (64 bit)
- WAMP Server 2.5
- Python 3.4
- Django 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the official mod_wsgi download area at all?

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases

All the release notes specifically say to read:

- https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/tree/master/win32